# how to analyze user's service usage time?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I'm sturggling making logic with PySpark(pandas), ElasticSearch(save the results aggregated to visualize).
(I'm newbie)

if the logs comes in this way,

| timestamp | id | service_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15:24:33 | A | X |
| 15:25:34 | A | Y |
| 15:27:22 | A | X |
| 17:33:28 | A | Z |
| 17:35:29 | A | Z |

The user 'A' used my service X,Y,Z (don't care about the service for now).
How can I measure the actual time usage (for all service now; no matter what service A used) for user 'A'?

Actual time: 'A' sent the logs at 15:24 ~ 15:27 so, 2 minutes,
and at 17:33~17:35 so, another 2 minutes.
total-> 4 minutes.

I have to judge that 'A' did not use my service between 15:27 ~ 17:33.

I'm not asking you whole alogorithms, but just tips like useful methods or skills in python, pandas or pyspark for this situation(need to calculate summation of time differences)

Because the logs come in 30m~40m per day, I have to care about the performance also.

It's a bit complicated, i know. Hard to explain. Thank you.

Comment: 1. [PySpark and Pandas](https://stackshare.io/stackups/pandas-vs-pyspark) are different things. 2. Imagine it as an RDB table with columns timestamp, id & service_id. Write SQL queries that will give you teh desired results, using things like `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` (or `PARTITION BY`) etc. Translate to corresponding PySpark SQL/API-calls.

Comment: saving the aggregated results in Elasticsearch makes sense for visualising, but why not store the data in Elasticsearch and then do this calculation there as well?